# Javascript - Regex - how to filter characters that are not part of regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to accept words and some special characters, so if my regex
does not fully match, let's say I display an error,

```
var re = /^[[:alnum:]\-_.&\s]+$/;
var string = 'this contains invalid chars like #@';
var valid = string.test(re);
```

but now I want to "filter" a phrase removing all characters not matching the regex ?

usualy one use replace, but how to list all characters not matching the regex ?

```
var validString = string.filter(re); // something similar to this
```

how do I do this ?

regards

---

Wiktor Stribiżew solution works fine :

```js
regex=/[^a-zA-Z\-_.&\s]+/g;
let s='some bloody-test @rfdsfds';
s = s.replace(/[^\w\s.&-]+/g, '');
console.log(s);
```

Rajesh solution :

```js
regex=/^[a-zA-Z\-_.&\s]+$/;
let s='some -test @rfdsfds';
s=s.split(' ').filter(x=> regex.test(x));
console.log(s);
```

Comment: look at string is a reserved word

Comment: JS regex engine does not support POSIX character classes like `[:alnum:]` (you may use `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead, but only to match ASCII letters and digits). you may try running `s.match(/[^\w\s.&-]/g)` to get the chars that do not match letters, digits, `_`, `.`, `&`, whitespace and `-`.

Comment: `string.split(' ').filter(x => !regex.test(x))`

Comment: but how to remove them afterwards ?

Comment: @Rajesh sadfully it does not filter anything, I modified my question

Comment: @phil1234 my approach was to get the list of words that are not qualified. So, you will also get `'abc#5'`, if this is in sentence. If you just wants to capture characters, try @Wiktor's answer.

Comment: Also, if you can share sample output for given input, it would be easier for us to resolve.

Comment: @phil1234 Your regex seems to be a bit off. https://regex101.com/r/xO9MDC/1. Its not matching any word. Updating regex to `/^[a-z0-9\-_.&\s]+$/i` solve the issue.

Comment: See my answer: 1) you cannot use `[:alnum:]`, 2) you need to use a *different* regex, yours can't find *partial* matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS regex engine does not support POSIX character classes like `[:alnum:]`. You may use `[A-Za-z0-9]` instead, but only to match ASCII letters and digits.

Your current regex matches the whole string that contains allowed chars, and it cannot be used to return the chars that are not matched with `[^a-zA-Z0-9_.&\s-]`.

You may remove the unwanted chars with

```js
var s = 'this contains invalid chars like #@';
var res = s.replace(/[^\w\s.&-]+/g, '');
var notallowedchars = s.match(/[^\w\s.&-]+/g);
console.log(res);
console.log(notallowedchars);
```

The `/[^\w\s.&-]+/g` pattern matches multiple occurrences (due to `/g`) of any one or more (due to `+`) chars other than word chars (digits, letters, `_`, matched with `\w`), whitespace (`\s`), `.`, `&` and `-`.

Comment: Why you need `[]+` if it's global replace?

Comment: @Justinas To remove matched streaks of chars in one go. It means fewer replacements made by the regex engine internally.

Comment: And how much is that faster then simple replace (if faster at all)?

Comment: @Justinas Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zoc96te3/). It is faster with the `+` quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

To match all characters that is not alphanumeric, or one of `-_.&` move `^` inside group `[]`

```js
var str = 'asd.=!_#$%^&*()564';

console.log(
    str.match(/[^a-z0-9\-_.&\s]/gi),
    str.replace(/[^a-z0-9\-_.&\s]/gi, '')
);
```